# How to encode HEVC tile in JPEG?

Tags: ffmpeg, jpeg, hevc, mp4box

I am trying to convert HEIF file into a JPEG file, I extract HEIC images tiles using MP4Box but when convert these tiles into JPEG using FFMPEG I get this :

> SAKATA-INX:desktop stellar$ MP4Box -dump-item 1:path=item1.hevc
>   still_rear.HEIC
>
> ICC colour profile not supported   ICC colour profile not supported
>
> SAKATA-INX:desktop stellar$ ffmpeg -i item1.hevc -frames:v 1 -vsync
>   vfr -q:v 1 -an test.jpg
>
> ffmpeg version 4.0 Copyright (c) 2000-2018 the FFmpeg developers built
>   with Apple LLVM version 9.1.0 (clang-902.0.39.1)
>
> configuration: --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/ffmpeg/4.0 --enable-shared
>   --enable-pthreads --enable-version3 --enable-hardcoded-tables --enable-avresample --cc=clang --host-cflags= --host-ldflags= --enable-gpl --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxvid --enable-opencl --enable-videotoolbox --disable-lzma
>
> libavutil      56. 14.100 / 56. 14.100
>
> libavcodec     58. 18.100 / 58. 18.100
>
> libavformat    58. 12.100 / 58. 12.100
>
> libavdevice    58.  3.100 / 58.  3.100
>
> libavfilter     7. 16.100 /  7. 16.100
>
> libavresample   4.  0.  0 /  4.  0.  0
>
> libswscale      5.  1.100 /  5.  1.100
>
> libswresample   3.  1.100 /  3.  1.100
>
> libpostproc    55.  1.100 / 55.  1.100
>
> [hevc @ 0x7fc56e808e00] Format hevc detected only with low score of 1,
>   misdetection possible!
>
> [hevc @ 0x7fc56f800000] No start code is found.
>
> [hevc @ 0x7fc56f800000] missing picture in access unit
>
> [AVBSFContext @ 0x7fc56e505e00] No start code is found.
>
> item1.hevc: could not find codec parameters
>
> Input #0, hevc, from 'item1.hevc':
>
> Duration: N/A, bitrate: N/A
>
> ```
> Stream #0:0: Video: hevc, none, 1200k tbn
> ```
>
> Output #0, image2, to 'test.jpg':
>
> Output file #0 does not contain any stream

Could any one tell me how I can do this ?

Comment: Which version of mp4box?

Comment: MP4Box - GPAC version 0.7.1-revrelease

Comment: ok, there were some bugs related to extracting HEIFs in Dec '17. Your build looks to be older. Get a nightly build or compile from latest source.

Comment: Could you tell me the commands for ffmpeg which convert hevc tiles to jpeg.

Comment: Your ffmpeg command is fine.

Comment: It works well, could please you tell me how to glue these 48 tiles in one jpg file by ffmpeg ? @Gyan

Comment: Do you want a grid i.e. images arranged in 8x6 layout?

Comment: @Gyan Yes, I want a grid of 48 tiles which I extracted in 8x6 layout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you have all HEVC files extracted, create a text file

```
file file1.hevc
file file2.hevc
file file3.hevc
...
file file48.hevc
```

and then run

```
ffmpeg -f concat -i list.txt -vf tile=8x6 -vframes 1 -q:v 1 grid.jpg
```

Comment: I use this command "for((i=1;i<=51;i++));do ffmpeg -i item$1.hevc -frames:v 1 -vsync vfr -q:v 1 -an test$1.jpg; done" and now I have 48 jpg tiles, I want to create a single image from these 48 tiles. How can I do this ?

Comment: Done, Thank you @Gyan

Comment: Can anyone tell me how to remove the black portion inside the jpeg image in right and below side after using the above command?